# Error: failed to request getAccount

Tags: associated-token-account

Does anyone know why I failed to request getAccount immediately after creating an Associated Token Account?
How can I verify that an Associated Account Token has been created?

Comment: would be useful to see any errors that may have been thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Might be due to misalignment of commitment between `sendTransaction` and `getAccount` you're using.

You can also use `getOrCreate` , might be easier for your needs:

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-program-library/token/js/modules.html#getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount